# Find constants $a_n$ and $b_n$ of a solution to a differential equation.

Tags: calculus

[image]

The working I have done so far but my question is how do I solve for $a_n$ (and furthermore $b_n$)?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The first equation implies all of the $a_n = 0$ except for $n=1$ and $n=3$, and the second equation implies all of the $b_n = 0$ except when $n=1$ and $n=4$. Can you see why? (Extra hint: think linear independence)

Comment: Right so $a_n=0$ except for $a_1=1$ and $a_3=2$.